# No trusted certificate when running notes java agent from server

Tags: java, ssl, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a Java agent which is doing a HTTPS POST:

```
            URL url = new URL("https://postman-echo.com/post");
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
            //Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            System.out.println("RESPONSE : "  + conn.getResponseMessage());
            return conn.getResponseMessage();
```

This POST works when running the agent on the server **manually**. If I am posting the agent scheduled or via the console by : tell amgr run
Then I am getting this error:

```
error message: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: No trusted certificate found
```

I truly have no idea why this is the case. Its running the agent with:
 1. Target set to None
 2. running with administrator ID
 3. Security Allow restricted operations with full administration rights

It worked last week and now not anymore..

**Update**
When doing a post to: https://postman-echo.com/post it works, also when running from server.
When doing post to my own website which has a comodo extended validation ssl then I get the no trusted certificate error

**Solution**
I have updated the Server from 9.0.1 FP4 to 9.0.1 FP10. It now posts data (from scheduled agent) to the HTTPS address without getting the error.

Comment: What version of domino are you running? Have you read this technote? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21985289

Comment: Server is running on 9.0.1 FP4

Comment: It is fixed. I have updated the Server from 9.0.1 FP4 to 9.0.1 FP10. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your java agent runs inside the JRE implemented in domino. As you are connecting via https you have to import the ssl certificate of the requested site to the truststore (cacert file) of the JRE. Otherwise the ssl handshake fails.
The location of the JRE on the server is /jvm/lib/security .

Comment: I have done this, I went to the website and downloaded the base64 .cer files and also of the whole chain. Installed it into cacerts and restarted the whole server. But still same exception.

Comment: Do you have to use a proxy to connect to the internet? Maybe you also have to trust the proxy certificate?

Comment: Did you also trust your self signed ssl certificate?

Comment: It is not a self signed certificate.

Comment: Even though I assume that you still have to import it - at least  If the cacert does not trust it (which is obviously the case)

Comment: In Domino/jvm/lib/security/cacerts I have imported all the certificates. What I have done is: open the website, click the padlock, download its certificate + its root certificate as base 64 .cer files and imported it in cacerts then restarted the server.